# GIT: fatal: Could not read from remote repository when you create new branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-config

I'm create new branch and I'm trying to push the branch (I have tried the following commands):

```
git push --all -u
git push origin NewBranch
```

But in both cases I'm getting this error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is my .git/config:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        ignorecase = true
        precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = ssh://git@github.com/myName/myRepo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = ssh://git@github.com/myName/myRepo.git
```

This is origin:

```
origin  ssh://git@github.com/myName/myRepo.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@github.com/myName/myRepo.git (push)
```

Any of you knows why of this error?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: The part of an ssh url between the `//` and the `@` should be your username.  I'm assuming your username is probably not `git`

Comment: On GitHub with SSH key the user is always `git`. Looks like there is a problem with the SSH key you are using that is not allowed to access your repository.

Answer (score 5):

Double-check:

- your [GitHub ssh setting](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/)
- the exact case (upercase/lowercase) of your url `myName/myRepo.git`
- if the issue persists with an https url

  ```
  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myName/myRepo.git
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if OP ever solved his issue or not, but for future references (since this helped myself not too long ago haha), the problem is with the SSH/OAuth authorization. I resolved my situation by replacing the OAuth for terminal access and updating my gitconfig file:

** OSX Sierra Platform **

1. Check your config file via the `git config -e` command.
2. Open your keychain app.
3. Search for github.com || org.github.com if you're in an organization's enterprise repo.
4. Select the keychain entry appropriate github -- OF TYPE "Internet Password".
5. Edit the password via pasting in the OAuth key.
6. Exit and retry to push to your repo, which should generate a pop-up asking for keychain access.

   - If so, allow access.
   - If not then you edited the wrong keychain or something didn't save correctly.

Git is documented on github pretty extensively, so if you run into a hiccup, just give it a quick search on there (or stackoverflow ...) and hopefully it won't be too hard to clear up. People are awesome at helping out, so don't be afraid to ask a dumb question!